# How to fix error; The method '[]' was called on null... Tried calling: [ ]("image")

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to copy a code from food-bit-app on github, to add to my codes. but after running it I get the error;

```
Tried calling: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("image")
```

I have tried to fix it but to no avail, this is the code;

```
class Details extends StatelessWidget {   static String page = 'details';   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    final Map screenArguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    Map product = screenArguments['products'];
    int index = screenArguments['index'];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Hero(
            tag: 'detail_food$index',
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              height: SizeConfig.screenHeight,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(product['image']), //The error points here
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          BodyDetails(),
        ],
      ),
    );   } }
```

The above code is pushed from this class(below) i.e. Navigator.pushNamed...

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: this.demoFoods.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> product = this.demoFoods[index];
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  'details',
                  arguments: {
                    'product': product,
                    'index': index,
                  },
                );
              },
```

Comment: I honestly don't know. I took it from github.. was trying to understand the code

Comment: and I think it is not supposed to be null but I don't know how I am gonna fix that. I am just trying to achieve the next page outputted to me but I keep getting that error

Comment: what do you think should be replaced or what do  u think I should do instead

Comment: @RichardBarker Any help?

Comment: ok I will do that

Comment: ok enough with these judgement Phrases "understand the code"... that is what i am trying to do over here... I have been reading the guys code from github and I tried working with it... I have understood all his code until I got to this part... I am darn confused here... isn't github an open source, and isn't this place supposed to be a helping place

Comment: Have u guys even read it to try and understand it yourself or try to figure it out, before judging me

Comment: I am waiting for the person who is smart and kind enough to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is in your code like below in pushNamed you passed the parameter as following

```
'product': product,
```

but when you received it in the second page you received it like this

```
Map product = screenArguments['products'];
```

if you see that you received it with (s) but you send it without this (s) i think this is the error here

i hope this is helpful for you

Comment: you my friend are the smartest guy over here... Thank you so much.... your patience and observation is on point. The world needs smart guys like you. Allah bless you

Comment: thank you i can't say anything after these really good words i really so happy that i helped you and solve your problem thanks so much

Comment: You are Welcome.. :)